# Aura Component fetch returns an Empty List

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-apps

This question has been asked a lot I know and I apologize but I've spent a couple of hours troubleshooting why my record list is empty when the components I've set up are very simple.

I am trying to get records from a custom object and display them as text in the Lightning App.
The custom object is called Order_Item__c.

Component: listOrdItems

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" controller="fetchOIDetails" >
    <aura:attribute name="oiList" type="Order_Item__c[]"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />  
    <aura:iteration var="item" items="{!v.oiList}" >
    <p>{!item.Name}</p>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

Controller: listOrdItemsController

```
({
   doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.fetchOIList");
        action.setCallback(this, function(data){
            component.set("v.oiList",data.getReturnValue()); 
        });
       console.log('this function ran');
     $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Server-side Component: fetchOIDetails

```
public class fetchOIDetails {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Order_Item__c> fetchOIList() {
        List<Order_Item__c> ordLst = new List<Order_Item__c>();
        ordLst = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Order_Item__c];
        return ordLst;
    }
}
```

Application:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:listOrditems/>
</aura:application>
```

Comment: Try to do a `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.serialize(data.getReturnValue()));` (inside the setCallback) to see what comes back form the server

Comment: @SergioAlcocer, I did that. Page is still blank.

Comment: check also the `data.getState()` to see if its 'SUCCESS' and do the console.log of the returned values. Alternatively, enable apex debug logs and see what you get back on apex-side

Comment: try to check getState() of the response before saving the response in your attribute.

    action.setCallback(this, function(data){
      var state = data.getState();
      if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
           console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.serialize(data.getReturnValue()));
          component.set("v.oiList",data.getReturnValue()); 
      }else{
          console.log('state '+ state);
      }           
     });

Comment: can you please check this query : SELECT Id,Name FROM Order_Item__c in query editor.how many records you will get???..

Comment: @ShagunSharma Hi, I've done this but can't save as it returns an error.
I've screen captured the error to view. https://imgur.com/HROxpaC

Also I have tested the state and it returns SUCCESS

Comment: @SFDCLearner I got all the 10 records.
Here is a screen shot of the query https://imgur.com/Klo8e9F

Comment: you need to add one more close bracket in your console 
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.serialize(data.getReturnValue())));
also a close bracket after else "}"

Comment: @ShagunSharma sorry about that, I ran the code you provided and got this error in the app https://imgur.com/MmNBu24

Answer (score 0):

I apologize to everyone, I really do not know what fixed it but it fixed itself. I have no idea what did it. I even created another org just to recreate the problem though I failed and so I decided to run the application again, then suddenly it showed the records and their names.